# Topology of this object 3-tree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I studied topology a long time ago and have forgotten how to stitch lines together. What would be the topological classification of this image? The lines extend to infinity so it is 3 copies of $\mathbb{R}^+$ stitched together at 0.

[image]

Comment: When you say "classification", do you mean "description"? Do you remember what "the quotient topology" is?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Probably, I've forgotten a lot of terminology. I expect it to be $\mathbb{R}^+ (+) \mathbb{R}^+ (+) \mathbb{R}^+$ or something like that?

Comment: No, its the quotient space of ${\mathbb R}_+\times \{1, 2, 3\}$ by the equivalence relation $0\times i\sim 0\times j$ for $i, j\in \{1, 2, 3\}$.